# How to create a String with carriage returns?

Tags: java, string

For a JUnit test I need a String which consists of multiple lines. But all I get is a single lined String. I tried the following:

```
    String str = ";;;;;;\n" +
                 "Name, number, address;;;;;;\n" + 
                 "01.01.12-16.02.12;;;;;;\n" + 
                 ";;;;;;\n" + 
                 ";;;;;;";
```

I also tried `\n\r` instead of `\n`. System.getProperty("line.separator") doesn't work too. it produces a `\n` in String and no carriage return. So how can I solve that?

Comment: I am not a java guy but just to help you here I think the correct sequence for a carriage return is **\r\n**

Comment: Where do you that it do not contain new line? In debugger or in output file?

Comment: The question is not clear if we look at the accepted answer.

Comment: While asking the question I didn't know that the problem is not related to a carriage return problem. If I would have changed the title of the question, people would have complained that all the other answers don't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers. I missed that my data is stored in a `List<String>` which is passed to the tested method. The mistake was that I put the string into the first element of the ArrayList. That's why I thought the String consists of just one single line, because the debugger showed me only one entry.

Answer (score 40):

It depends on what you mean by "multiple lines". Different operating systems use different line separators.

In Java, `\r` is always carriage return, and `\n` is line feed. On Unix, just `\n` is enough for a newline, whereas many programs on Windows require `\r\n`. You can get at the platform default newline use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` or use `String.format("%n")` as mentioned in other answers.

But really, you need to know whether you're *trying* to produce OS-specific newlines - for example, if this is text which is going to be transmitted as part of a specific protocol, then you should see what *that protocol* deems to be a newline. For example, [RFC 2822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt) defines a line separator of `\r\n` and this should be used *even if you're running on Unix*. So it's all about context.

Answer (score 9):

The fastest way I know to generate a new-line character in Java is: `String.format("%n")`

Of course you can put whatever you want around the `%n` like:

`String.format("line1%nline2")`

Or even if you have a lot of lines:

`String.format("%s%n%s%n%s%n%s", "line1", "line2", "line3", "line4")`

Comment: Note that `%n` depends on the platform.

Answer (score 3):

Try `\r\n` where `\r` is carriage return. Also ensure that your output do not have new line, because debugger can show you special characters in form of `\n`, `\r`, `\t` etc.

Comment: That doesn't work either. Now I've got a String which contains \r\n instead of new lines.

Comment: Where do you that it do not contain new line? In debugger or in output file?

Answer (score 2):

Do this:
Step 1: Your String

```
String str = ";;;;;;\n" +
            "Name, number, address;;;;;;\n" + 
             "01.01.12-16.02.12;;;;;;\n" + 
             ";;;;;;\n" + 
             ";;;;;;";
```

Step 2: Just replace all "\n" with "%n" the result looks like this

```
String str = ";;;;;;%n" +
             "Name, number, address;;;;;;%n" + 
             "01.01.12-16.02.12;;;;;;%n" + 
            ";;;;;;%n" + 
            ";;;;;;";
```

Notice I've just put "%n" in place of "\n"

Step 3: Now simply call format()

```
str=String.format(str);
```

That's all you have to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try append characters `.append('\r').append('\n');` instead of String `.append("\\r\\n");`