# Java \n line separator not working

Tags: java, string, performance, syntax, newline

I am creating an application that has a data log. I build up this data with a string that I add to everytime the application receives data and then display it in an edittext box.

The problem I am having is that it will display the data but without the new lines.

A basic example of the code:

```
String logText;
EditText etLog;

logText = data + "\n" + logText;
etLog.setText(logText);
```

I know that I can use `nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");` to get a new line but I'm puzzled as to why "\n" is not working when I've used it in different apps I've created before.

Comment: You can also check the answers to this question: [How to create a String with carriage returns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989414/how-to-create-a-string-with-carriage-returns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not overly keen on answering my own question but I solved it by changing the inputType of my EditText to textMultiLine in my xml code. 
xml code:

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

Allows the EditText to make use of "\n" within a string.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the problem arises because of a particular programs preferences. The `\n`(new line feed) is one possibility, but there is also `\r` aka carriage return.

The two are essentially the same, just that there's a standardisation issue. Java uses both for compatibility. Try one, the other, both. Usually one will work.

For editText, I believe its `\r\n`.