# What is the best Java 8 Character method for detecting no character?

Tags: java, character, isnull

I've got a simple program, written in Java, and I am trying to find a way to validate that anything at all has been entered before the user hits "enter" in the console.  Currently, I'm using isLetter() to ensure that a letter has been entered, but this doesn't seem to prevent someone from entering nothing and hitting enter.  I've tried several methods in the documentation, and can't seem to locate one that works.

For the snippet below, I'm showing how I've successfully censured that the input variable "letter" is a single character, and will always be a single character, but this doesn't prevent a user from hitting "enter" after typing nothing.

```
 if (! Character.isLetter(letter)) {  //Don't forget to validate for no chars entered!
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("A letter is required");
```

Comment: You haven't shown how you've initialized `letter` to start with, which doesn't help. When debugging through this code, what have you observed as the value of `letter` when the user *does* just hit return?

Comment: You need to show more context. How are you filling `letter`?

Comment: The code obtains the character by prompting with a readLine and then using charAt(0) to get the first character of what is entered:  String guessAsString = console.readLine("Enter a letter: ");
        char guess = guessAsString.charAt(0);  "guess" becomes letter through the function for validating guess from which the original snippet game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using a `readLine()` call, and typically, `readLine()` calls don't include the line termination characters in the return value, why don't you just do:

```
if (!yourInput.equals("")) {/* code */}
```

In fact, you can put that even before you try to `charAt(0)`

Comment: That's a good point, and I think that's generally what people do, and the code could be refactored that way, but I was curious about what to do about a blank character, not a string.

Comment: @AlexWall When you readLine(), you automatically get a string though - You can't check `charAt(0)` of an empty string (which is what you get when you "just press enter") - there is nothing at index 0. Unless you're talking about if the user entered a space and THEN pressed enter... in which case you'll still never be able to detect '\r' and '\n' since `readLine()` doesn't include line termination characters. If you want to avoid THAT scenario, just do a `trim()` on your input, and this method will work again.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that makes total sense!

Answer (score 1):

Hitting the <kbd>Enter</kbd> will [produce the carriage-return symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9989507/1003142), so you can just do this comparison:

```
if (letter != '\r' && letter != '\n') { ... }
```